# How to move turtle to a specific spot but set pixel of the moves randomly?

Tags: python, command, turtle-graphics

How can I make a turtle move step by step (set the steps value randomly to 1-10 pixels) in the length of 1000 pixels?

this is what i have so far

```
import turtle; 
import random; 
turtle.fd(random.randrange(1,10))
```

Comment: first you get the turtle position and then you keep moving the turtle until it has traveled 1000 pixels ...

Comment: How would it be written in codes?

Comment: The site is meant for programming problems, not for expecting others to do your work. Please tell us what you have tried and what you are stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

since you seem to simply want an answer that works here is one

```
from random import randint as ri
from itertools import takewhile as tw
import turtle as t
steps = [1,10]
it = iter(lambda:(t.fd(ri(*steps)) or 1),object())
print "Takes %d steps"%(sum(tw(lambda x:1e3-t.position()[0]>steps[-1],it))+1)
```